# Loop php array stored in one SQL cell

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select, stored-procedures

I have a table which contains body of xml document (like php array):

```
a:26:{s:4:"HEAD";a:1:{i:0;a:8:{s:5:"BUYER";s:13:"4640014349991";a:5:{s:7:"varGUID";s:3:" ";}s:8:"POSITION";a:17:{i:0;a:14:{s:14:"POSITIONNUMBER";s:1:"1";s:11:"DESCRIPTION";s:67:"Value 0";s:9:"UNITPRICE";s:5:"11.40";}i:1;a:14:{s:14:"POSITIONNUMBER";s:1:"2";s:11:"DESCRIPTION";s:69:"Value 1";s:9:"UNITPRICE";}i:2;}}s:7:"ECONINF";s:46:"Text";}
```

One cell for one document.

Now I need to found for example all of `UNITPRICE` which is duplicating, so I should iterate this SQL cell to find all of `UNITPRICE`. How I can do this?

I am trying to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` for this, but it is not working because I think that substring will be show only first value of `UNITPRICE` in cell:

```
SELECT d.varName AS "Name 1", 
c.varName AS "Name 2",
a.varDocNum AS "Number",
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.`xmlBody`, '"PRODUCTIDBUYER";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) AS "PRODUCTIDBUYER",
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.`xmlBody`, '"DESCRIPTION";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) AS "DESCRIPTION",
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.`xmlBody`, '"UNITPRICE";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) AS "UNITPRICE"

FROM xmls AS a
LEFT JOIN xmls_body AS b ON a.intDocID = b.intDocID
LEFT JOIN adresses AS c ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.`xmlBody`, '"BUYER";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1)=c.varAdress
LEFT JOIN adresses AS d ON a.varSender=d.varAdress

WHERE a.varRecipient in ('4640014349991')
AND a.intSendTimestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-02-09 23:59:59')
AND a.intSendTimestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-09 00:00:00')

AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.`xmlBody`,'"PRODUCTIDBUYER";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) IN(
'110324',
'103208'
)
AND c.varName LIKE '%1065%'
OR '%1008%'
```

**UPD:**

**I've create procedures like:**

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE PROCEDURE prcdProduct()
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(q.`xmlBody`, '"DESCRIPTION";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) AS "Product"  FROM xmls_body AS q;
END 
|
DELIMITER ;
```

**but I am getting error:**

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL prcdProduct(),
```

**when I am trying to use stored procedure:**

```
SELECT d.varName AS "Supplier", 
c.varName AS "Shop",
a.varDocNum AS "УПД",
CALL prcdProduct(),
...
```

if I delete `CALL` I will have error that `FUNCTION dbName.prcdProduct does not exist`. But this I think because of without `CALL` we are executing functions, not `PROCEDURE`

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: You really should be doing this in PHP...

Comment: @Nick, 5.6.36-82.0-log

Comment: Yes, but I haven't access to server where this db stores, so only SQL

Comment: For that MySQL version I'm pretty sure you'll need to use a stored procedure to iterate over the string.

Comment: How I can do this? What kind of stored procedure?

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures/

Comment: So it's should be: `DELIMITER //
 
CREATE PROCEDURE prcd()
BEGIN
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(q.`xmlBody`, '"UNITPRICE";',-1),'"',2),'"',-1) AS "UNITPRICE"  FROM xmls_body AS q;
END //
 
DELIMITER ;` instead of just SUBSTRING_INDEX?

Comment: How can I pass arguments like "UNITPRICE" in prcd()?

Comment: The point of a stored procedure is to loop over the values, so you would find the first occurrence of `UNITPRICE`, strip that part out of the string, and then look for `UNITPRICE` again, and so on until you don't find it any more.

Comment: I have updated my question